# Android: Best Practices When Calling Intents From OnBackPressed()

Tags: android, button, android-intent

Bonjur! The following code is meant to be a back button override on an activity within an Android application that returns the user to the previous page.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //building new intent to go back to the main menu

    Intent openMainMenu = new Intent ("com.developmentsfoo.foobarbab.MAINMENU");
    startActivity(openMainMenu);

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

My question is that this intent is already called, in practically the same context in another .java as part of an onClick. Is there a way to call intents from other methods on other pages, or is it best practice to make a new intent on the page where you mean to go back? Does it increase overhead at all? will a simple setContentView method work in some case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnBackPressed() basically kills your activity from the activity stack,So for this you need to call finish() ans you ll be automatically be at the activity behind this killable activty.

Answer (score 1):

If it came from **MainMenu.class** already and you have to do `finish()` from while going from your current activity to another, you don't need to do onBackPress as it will automatically go back there since it's in activity stack when you press the back button.

Comment: Good call out. I have a bit of confusion however when you talk about where to place the finish method. Yes, the new activity is coming from the main menu, so the first part is true, but where are you putting finish? I currently have it nested in an onBackPress method because ADT doesn't like it just sitting out in the open. Says it needs a body. The only other method I have is onCreate but wouldn't that kill the page the minute it is made?